# How to adjust the screen for many types of screens in Android using Unity 3.5x?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, screen-resolution

I have a project and I want to build it for Android. I want to know, how to adjust the screen so I can play it well in many types of Android's phones? (Since there are so many type of screens for Android). I already tried many ways to do it, include the one in this thread : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/161281/is-there-a-way-to-android-physical-screen-size.html, and using Screen.height and Screen.widht, but I can't do it.
By the way, I'm using C#.
Do anyone have some solutions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved the problem with made a new class and scaling the panel which I put the background (so each of the gameobject will be scaling as well).

Answer (score 0):

The size of the screen isn't important because unity do the work for you. The only problem is the ratio of the screen.

You need to test your application on 16/9 screen and 16/10 screen

Comment: I've already tested it in Samsung Galaxy SII, Galaxy Mini, Sony Ericson Experia. But each of them return different size. So I'm confused. By the way, I forgot to write before, but the problem is with the 2D Menu. The 3D is appear well I think. (I use NGUI plugin for 2D menu)

Comment: Sorry, I don't use this plugin but to resolve that you can make your menu in 3D!